# Msbuild is publishing all folders and source code

Tags: visual-studio-2013, deployment, msbuild, publish, asp.net-mvc-5

I've a solution with two pprojects mvc5 web app and tests.
If I publish the web site as file system by right click and publish with a custom profile it's all good.
Specifying that custom profile from command line leads to all folders/source code in the solution being published.
There's something I'm missing but I don't know where to look anymore.

msbuild C:\eqsnet452\Eqs.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=IntegrationPublish /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0

The IntegrationPublish profile is set to File System but all files get copied in the pusblished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the Application's Properties in VS, under "Package/Publish Web" menu item, there is an option "Items to deploy".

There you have three options, one of which is: "Only files needed to run this application". You have to choose this option for each Configuration you want.

Hope this helps.